# If you stop a QTimer, will it emit a timeout() signal?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to understand the operation of a QTimer.  I have things triggered off timeout() signals, but I am unable to find in the documentation if a timeout() signal is emitted if I stop the timer early.

Basically, how can I force a timeout() before the timer finishes counting?  Just hack by restarting the timer with the minimum ms increment?

```
myTimer->start(1);
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtimer.html#timeout

Comment: I am confused and probably missing something. If you stop a timer manually, you can also call whatever function would have been called by its timeout manually. I guess there is some complication that I am overlooking in what are asking?

Comment: "I am unable to find in the documentation if a timeout() signal is emitted if I stop the timer early." That's why you've got Qt Creator. Creating a new project and typing in the code needed to test this should take you less than 60 seconds :) That's the power of Qt :)

Comment: True, true @KubaOber

Answer (score 11):

In neither Qt 4 nor Qt 5 can you directly emit `QTimer::timeout` from outside of the class. It's a private signal: in Qt 4, it's declared as `private`, in Qt 5, it's declared with an argument of a private type [`QObjectPrivate`](https://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work-part2-qt5.html).

You can invoke it, though:

```
// fast, guaranteed to work in Qt 4 and 5
myTimer->QTimer::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, 5, {});

// slower, has to look up the method by name
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(myTimer, "timeout");
```

In Qt 5, the moc-generated `QTimer::qt_static_metacall` constructs the private argument for us:

```
//...
case 0: _t->timeout(QPrivateSignal()); break;
```

You can also make the timer act as if it had timed out by sending it a timer event:

```
void emitTimeout(QTimer * timer) {
  Q_ASSERT(timer);
  QTimerEvent event{timer->timerId()};
  QCoreApplication::sendEvent(timer, &event);
}
```

Both methods work on both Qt 4 and Qt 5.

Since you're looking to emit a timeout on stopping an active timer, the solutions would be, respectively:

```
void emitTimeoutAndStop(QTimer * timer) {
  Q_ASSERT(timer);
  Q_ASSERT(QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()); // event loop must be on the stack
  if (!timer->isActive()) return;
  timer->QTimer::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod, 5, {});
  timer->stop();
}
```

or

```
void emitTimeoutAndStop(QTimer * timer) {
  Q_ASSERT(timer);
  Q_ASSERT(QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()); // event loop must be on the stack
  if (!timer->isActive()) return;
  QTimerEvent event{timer->timerId()};
  QCoreApplication::sendEvent(timer, &event);
  timer->stop();
}
```

The signals will be emitted immediately, and not by Qt code from the event loop. This shouldn't be a problem, since `emitTimeoutAndStop` will be invoked with an event loop on the stack. We assert that fact. If you wish to support invoking `emitTimeoutAndStop` from code tied to the same timer's `timeout` signal without reentering said code, then you have to use the `ChattyTimer` below, or [the solution from another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36609258/1329652).

If all you need isn't quite a timer, but just an immediate, single-emission signal, `QObject::destroyed` is useful for that purpose. It will be emitted at the end of the block, where `source` goes out of scope and is destructed.

```
{ QObject source;
  connect(&source, &QObject::destroyed, ...); }
```

Alternatively, you can have a small helper class:

```
// signalsource.h
#pragma once
#include <QObject>
class SignalSource : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void signal();
  SignalSource(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {}
};
```

Since you can connect multiple signals to a single receiver, perhaps it would make things clearer to connect both a timer and such a signal source to the receiver, instead of trying to hack around timer's behavior.

On the other hand, if such "signaling upon stopping" timer is something you find useful in several places, it'd be better to actually implement it as a dedicated class - it's not all that hard. Re-using the `QTimer` class is not possible, since the `stop()` slot is not virtual, and thus `ChattyTimer` is not Liskov-substitutable for a `QTimer`. This would be a bug waiting to happen - in the class of bugs that are hard to find.

**There are several behavioral details that demand attention. This perhaps indicates that changing the behavior of something as fundamental as a timer is tricky** - you never know what code might make assumptions that are obviously correct in `QTimer`, but not so when `stop()` might emit a timeout. It is a good idea to have all this in a class that is not-a `QTimer` - it really is not!

1. As in `QTimer`, the timeout event is always emitted from the event loop. To have it emitted immediately from `stop()`, set `immediateStopTimeout`.
2. There are two generalizations possible of `isActive` behavior upon stop (vs. that of `QTimer`):

   - becomes false immediately after `stop` returns, even if the final `timeout` will be emitted later, or
   - indicates whether timeout events may be emitted by the event loop, and will remain `true` after a `stop()` if the final `timeout` signal is deferred.

   I chose the first behavior to be the default. Set `activeUntilLastTimeout` to select the second behavior.
3. There are three generalizations possible of the behavior of each of `timerId` and `remainingTime` upon stop (vs. that of `QTimer`):

   - returns `-1` when `isActive()` is false, or a valid identifier/time otherwise (i.e. follows chosen `isActive()` behavior),
   - becomes `-1` immediately after `stop` returns, even if the final `timeout` will be emitted later,
   - returns a valid id/time whenever timeout events may still be emitted by the event loop.

   I chose the first behavior for both `timerId` and `remainingTime`, and it is not otherwise configurable.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/chattytimer-25695203
// chattytimer.h
#pragma once
#include <QAbstractEventDispatcher>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QTimerEvent>
class ChattyTimer : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(bool active READ isActive)
   Q_PROPERTY(int remainingTime READ remainingTime)
   Q_PROPERTY(int interval READ interval WRITE setInterval)
   Q_PROPERTY(bool singleShot READ singleShot WRITE setSingleShot)
   Q_PROPERTY(Qt::TimerType timerType READ timerType WRITE setTimerType)
   Q_PROPERTY(bool immediateStopTimeout READ immediateStopTimeout WRITE setImmediateStopTimeout)
   Q_PROPERTY(bool activeUntilLastTimeout READ activeUntilLastTimeout WRITE setActiveUntilLastTimeout)
   Qt::TimerType m_type = Qt::CoarseTimer;
   bool m_singleShot = false;
   bool m_stopTimeout = false;
   bool m_immediateStopTimeout = false;
   bool m_activeUntilLastTimeout = false;
   QBasicTimer m_timer;
   int m_interval = 0;
   void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) override {
      if (ev->timerId() != m_timer.timerId()) return;
      if (m_singleShot || m_stopTimeout) m_timer.stop();
      m_stopTimeout = false;
      emit timeout({});
   }
public:
   ChattyTimer(QObject * parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {}
   Q_SLOT void start(int msec) {
      m_interval = msec;
      start();
   }
   Q_SLOT void start() {
      m_stopTimeout = false;
      m_timer.stop(); // don't emit the signal here
      m_timer.start(m_interval, m_type, this);
   }
   Q_SLOT void stop() {
      if (!isActive()) return;
      m_timer.stop();
      m_stopTimeout = !m_immediateStopTimeout;
      if (m_immediateStopTimeout)
         emit timeout({});
      else // defer to the event loop
         m_timer.start(0, this);
   }
   Q_SIGNAL void timeout(QPrivateSignal);
   int timerId() const {
      return isActive() ? m_timer.timerId() : -1;
   }
   bool isActive() const {
      return m_timer.isActive() && (m_activeUntilLastTimeout || !m_stopTimeout);
   }
   int remainingTime() const {
      return
            isActive()
            ? QAbstractEventDispatcher::instance()->remainingTime(m_timer.timerId())
            : -1;
   }
   int interval() const { return m_interval; }
   void setInterval(int msec) {
      m_interval = msec;
      if (!isActive()) return;
      m_timer.stop(); // don't emit the signal here
      start();
   }
   bool singleShot() const { return m_singleShot; }
   void setSingleShot(bool s) { m_singleShot = s; }
   Qt::TimerType timerType() const { return m_type; }
   void setTimerType(Qt::TimerType t) { m_type = t; }
   bool immediateStopTimeout() const { return m_immediateStopTimeout; }
   void setImmediateStopTimeout(bool s) { m_immediateStopTimeout = s; }
   bool activeUntilLastTimeout() const { return m_activeUntilLastTimeout; }
   void setActiveUntilLastTimeout(bool s) { m_activeUntilLastTimeout = s; }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

> If you stop a QTimer, will it emit a timeout() signal?

No.

> Basically, how can I force a timeout() before the timer finishes
>   counting? Just hack by restarting the timer with the minimum ms
>   increment?

Call stop() on the timer, and then cause the signal to be emitted yourself.  You could do this by subclassing QTimer and calling a method in your QTimer subclass that emits the signal:

```
void MyQTimer :: EmitTimeoutSignal() {emit timeout();}
```

… but if you don't want to go to the bother of making a subclass, an easier approach would be to add a signal to your own class and connect that signal to the QTimer object's timeout() signal (do this only once of course):

```
connect(this, SIGNAL(MyTimeoutSignal()), myTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()));
```

… and then your stop-and-fire method would could be done like this:

```
myTimer->stop();
emit MyTimeoutSignal();
```

Comment: Note: This answer is valid for Qt 4, but *not* for Qt 5 - none of the above will work as written in Qt 5. Qt 5 makes many signals indirectly private by requiring an argument that you cannot construct...

Comment: I was wrong: the second way - connecting to `QTimer::timeout` - should work using the Qt 4 connect syntax in Qt 5, since moc hides the `QPrivateSignal` from the signature and doesn't require it to be passed around in signal-slot connections. The value is generated in `qt_static_metacall`, and doesn't come from the invoking signal. It won't work with Qt 5 connect syntax, though.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite easy to do this, at least in 4.8 and later (not sure about earlier versions): simply `setInterval(0)` (much like you suggest in your question, although there's no need to stop the timer and restart it).

This app will immediately print "Timer expired" and exit:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

  QTimer timer;
  timer.setSingleShot(true);
  timer.setInterval(1000 * 60 * 60); // one hour

  QObject::connect(
      &timer,  &QTimer::timeout,
      [&]()
      {
        std::cout << "Timer expired" << std::endl;
        app.exit();
      });

  QTimer::singleShot(
      0, //trigger immediately once QtEventLoop is running
      [&]()
      {
        timer.start();
        timer.setInterval(0);  // Comment this out to run for an hour.
      });

  app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Of course, `app.exit()` hides the need to stop the timer. In most applications, the timer wouldn't be used to exit the application, and must be explicitly stopped. In any case, timer events are delivered by the event loop, so there's no need to start the timer using the `singleShot` indirection. The code from the second lambda could be written directly within the body of `main()`. This answer would be better aftercorrecting these two deficiencies.

Comment: @KubaOber I don't understand your point about "the need to stop the timer". It's a single-shot timer, so it won't fire again. In any case, that doesn't have anything to do with the question, which is how to trigger the callback before the originally specified interval expires.

Comment: It is a single-shot timer because you made it so. The question didn't specify that. Also, I noticed another problem: `timer.start()` followed by `timer.setInterval` is wasteful: it will start the timer, then stop it, then start it again. Your answer could be summarized as: "`timer.setInterval(0); timer.setSingleShot(true);`" will - if the timer was active - cause immediate emission of the timeout event from the event loop, and will stop the timer then. Perhaps also preserve the original timer's properties, and restore them after such a way of "stopping and signaling" the timer.

Comment: @KubaOber I understand the question isn't about single-shot timers; I just used one in this code, and the *only* point of this code is to demonstrate that the callback is invoked immediately. The fact that the callback is invoked immediately is unrelated to the single-shot property.

Comment: In short: this isn't intended to be copy-and-paste "here's how you do it" code, it's *just* a demonstration of the fact that `setInterval(0)` causes the callback to be invoked immediately.